# Why does the 11th Doctor call Clara's future self before he regenerates?

Tags: doctor-who

In Series 8 Episode 1 Deep Breath Clara gets a call from a very familiar voice:

> CLARA: Hello? Hello?
>
> DOCTOR 11 [OC]: It's me.
>
> CLARA: Yes, it's you. Who's this?
>
> DOCTOR 11 [OC]: It's me, Clara. The Doctor.
>
> CLARA: What do you mean, the Doctor?
>
> DOCTOR 11: I'm phoning you from Trenzalore.
>
> CLARA: I don't
>
> DOCTOR 11: From before I changed. I mean it's all still to happen for me. It's coming. Oh, it's a-coming.
>   (Back then, Clara replaced the Tardis police phone back on its hook.)
>
> DOCTOR 11: Not long now. I can feel it.
>
> CLARA: Why? Why would you do this?
>
> DOCTOR 11: Because I think it's going to be a whopper, and I think you might be scared. And however scared you are, Clara, the man you are with right now, the man I hope you are with, believe me, he is more scared than anything you can imagine right now and he, he needs you.
>
> DOCTOR: So who is it?
>
> DOCTOR 11: Is that the Doctor?
>
> DOCTOR: Is that the Doctor?
>
> CLARA: Yes.
>
> DOCTOR 11: He sounds old. Please tell me I didn't get old. Anything but old. I was young. Oh, is he grey?
>
> CLARA: Yes.
>
> DOCTOR 11: Clara, please, hey, for me, help him. Go on. And don't be afraid. Goodbye, Clara. Miss ya.

Then this conversation happens about why his predecessor called her:

> DOCTOR: Well?
>
> CLARA: Well what?
>
> DOCTOR: He asked you a question. Will you help me?
>
> CLARA: You shouldn't have been listening.
>
> DOCTOR: I wasn't. I didn't need to. That was me talking. You can't see me, can you? You look at me, and you can't see me. Have you any idea what that's like? I'm not on the phone, I'm right here, standing in front of you. Please, just, just see me.
>   (Clara walks forward and studies his face carefully. Then she smiles a little.)
>
> CLARA: Thank you.
>
> DOCTOR: For what?
>
> CLARA: Phoning.

Why does the 11th Doctor call Clara's future self before he regenerates?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### He calls her to reassure her.

Before he regenerates, the 11th Doctor knows that Clara may not be comfortable with his new face. He's seen it all before, most recently when Rose didn't trust him after he regenerated from 9th to 10th Doctor. He wants to do everything he can to make her get on well with his own future self (the 12th Doctor).

So he makes a phone call to her in the future, and tells her that his future self is as nervous as she is and needs her companionship and support. It says so in the very dialogue you provide in your question (*yes, once again you've asked a question which includes so much dialogue that you've essentially answered it yourself*):

> CLARA: Why? Why would you do this?
>   DOCTOR 11: Because I think it's going to be a whopper, and I think you might be scared. And however scared you are, Clara, the man you are with right now, the man I hope you are with, believe me, he is more scared than anything you can imagine right now and he, he needs you.

This phone call also serves the purpose of **proving to Clara that the 11th and 12 Doctors are the same man**. When she realises that the 12 Doctor remembers being the 11th Doctor and making that call, she finally accepts that this grey-haired Scotsman really is her Doctor:

> CLARA: You shouldn't have been listening.
>   DOCTOR: I wasn't. I didn't need to. That was me talking. You can't see me, can you? You look at me, and you can't see me. Have you any idea what that's like? I'm not on the phone, I'm right here, standing in front of you. Please, just, just see me.
>   (Clara walks forward and studies his face carefully. Then she smiles a little.)
>   CLARA: Thank you.
>   DOCTOR: For what?
>   CLARA: Phoning.
>   (She throws her arms around his neck.)

That's the moment when she finally accepts the 12th Doctor. A beautiful moment of understanding.